# Find point and elliptic curve given the public key

Tags: cryptography, public-key, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to resolve this problem. Once the public key is known, I want to know which point and elliptic curve was used to generate that public key.

For example, given this ECC public key:

`04 6b fb ee c6 9d e7 2c 66 a6 68 ec e1 aa f1 a2 64 a3 c9 b2 88 fb 32 d0 59 e9 2c 3e 5d 5b d4 d7 b5 01 48 78 f4 47 9c 13 c8 83 d0 54 55 5c d9 0e cd 13 6e c4 cc 34 64 89 cd d6 4e 69 43 f3 33 86 4a b9 df e4 42 dc bf 8f 69 c1 9e 71 d0 35 ff 31 7f c0 32 fc 21 55 ca ea a6 5b 49 3d 19 1d 39 9a c0`

How is it possible to know which point and elliptic curve were used to generate that ECC public key?

Comment: You should ask that question @ [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Imho there is no easy and effective way to do it if the only thing you know is public key.

Comment: @Qiu On the other hand, on crypto avm_69 would not have gotten the code :P

Comment: Please do not remove the content of your question. To mark a question as resolved, [mark the answer that helped you most as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Also upvote all the answers that helped you.

Answer (score 4):

If the elliptic curve is one of the [recommended elliptic curves for Federal Government use](https://oag.ca.gov/sites/all/files/agweb/pdfs/erds1/fips_pub_07_2013.pdf) you can easily find out the domain parameters `(p,a,b,G,n,h)` where `G` is the `base point` and the bit length of the public key will tell you the curve name.

The EC public key is a point on a curve, like this: `y^2 = x^3 + ax + b (mod p)` where `p` is the prime modulus.

The point is represented as an octet string in compressed or uncompressed forms as per [ANSI X9.62](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt).

So the sample public key you mention consist of an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate:

> Public Key = tag + x co-ordinate + y co-ordinate

The uncompressed form is indicated by `tag = 0x04` and the compressed form is indicated by either `tag = 0x02` or `tag = 0x03` ([see section 2.2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5480.txt))

Now, the sample public key can be written as:

> 04
>   6bfbeec69de72c66a668ece1aaf1a264a3c9b288fb32d059e92c3e5d5bd4d7b5014878f4479c13c883d054555cd90ecd
>   136ec4cc346489cdd64e6943f333864ab9dfe442dcbf8f69c19e71d035ff317fc032fc2155caeaa65b493d191d399ac0

The length of each co-ordinate is 48 bytes or 384 bits. So it 'seems that' the sample public key is from the **EC P-384** curve.

[image]

Comment: Please use code formatting only for code, not for random words.

Comment: @Gilles, roger that, sir.

Comment: This answer is well setup and descriptive. It's also easy to verify that it is incorrect. The curve used is a Brainpool curve, not a NIST one.

Comment: Dear @MaartenBodewes sir, I just tried to say OP a way how to find the curve name where the curve is NIST recommend. That's why my answer starts with "if". Still if you demand than I can remove my answer.

Comment: I'm fine with an edit of the answer to indicate that it may also be another curve (i.e. the Brainpool one). I'm not on a crusade or anything, it's just that wrong is wrong. The rest of the answer is nice enough that we should keep it :)

Answer (score 2):

You should check each and every known (named) curve in order of probability. The probability depends of course on the situation, I don't know where you retrieved the point from.

So you do the following:

1. loop through all the named curves you can find;
2. check if the point is valid on the curve and not infinity.

Now if you do this you'll find this is a BrainpoolP384r1 curve, not a NIST curve.

---

OK, because otherwise this Java code will rot:

```java
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.nist.NISTNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.sec.SECNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.teletrust.TeleTrusTNamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X962NamedCurves;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x9.X9ECParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.math.ec.ECPoint;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class CurveFinder {

    interface CurveRetriever {
        X9ECParameters getByName(String name);
        Enumeration<String> getNames();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] wd = Hex.decode("04 6b fb ee c6 9d e7 2c 66 a6 68 ec e1 aa f1 a2 64 a3 c9 b2 88 fb 32 d0 59 e9 2c 3e 5d 5b d4 d7 b5 01 48 78 f4 47 9c 13 c8 83 d0 54 55 5c d9 0e cd 13 6e c4 cc 34 64 89 cd d6 4e 69 43 f3 33 86 4a b9 df e4 42 dc bf 8f 69 c1 9e 71 d0 35 ff 31 7f c0 32 fc 21 55 ca ea a6 5b 49 3d 19 1d 39 9a c0".replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
        String name = findCurveName(wd);
        if (name == null) {
            System.out.println("Curve not found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Curve: " + name);
        }
    }

    private static String findCurveName(byte[] wd) {
        List<CurveRetriever> retrievers = new LinkedList<>();
        retrievers.add(new CurveRetriever() {
            @Override
            public X9ECParameters getByName(String name) {
                return SECNamedCurves.getByName(name);
            }

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getNames() {
                return SECNamedCurves.getNames();
            }
        });
        retrievers.add(new CurveRetriever() {
            @Override
            public X9ECParameters getByName(String name) {
                return TeleTrusTNamedCurves.getByName(name);
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getNames() {
                return TeleTrusTNamedCurves.getNames();
            }
        });
        retrievers.add(new CurveRetriever() {
            @Override
            public X9ECParameters getByName(String name) {
                return NISTNamedCurves.getByName(name);
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getNames() {
                return NISTNamedCurves.getNames();
            }
        });
        retrievers.add(new CurveRetriever() {
            @Override
            public X9ECParameters getByName(String name) {
                return X962NamedCurves.getByName(name);
            }
            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getNames() {
                return X962NamedCurves.getNames();
            }
        });
        for (CurveRetriever curveRetriever : retrievers) {
            String name = retrieveAndValidate(wd, curveRetriever);
            if (name != null) {
                return name;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String retrieveAndValidate(byte[] wd,
            CurveRetriever retriever) {
        ECPoint decodedPoint = null;
        Enumeration<String> names = retriever.getNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = names.nextElement();
            X9ECParameters curveParams = retriever.getByName(name);
            try {
                decodedPoint = curveParams.getCurve().decodePoint(wd);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                continue;
            }
            if (decodedPoint.isInfinity() || !decodedPoint.isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

obviously this code requires the lightweight API of Bouncy Castle. I don't know why I didn't use the Bouncy Castle provider for the JCE instead - this one offers more control over curves I guess.

Comment: The public key was retrieved from this website https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/CSCA/csca-germany_101_self_signed_cer.zip?__blob=publicationFile and you can find more info here https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Topics/ElectrIDDocuments/CSCAcertGermany/cscaGermany_node.html                                                                 Taking into account that it is a Brainpool curve, how is it possible to know which is the point used?

Comment: Link certificates either specify the parameters explicitly or they "borrow" the parameters from the previous certificate (the very first certificate *must* include the parameters. The public point itself is of course included in the certificate, it was generated together with the private value $s$, which is in a HSM somewhere. The generator g, also a point, is part of the parameters.

Comment: So, it is a brainpool curve and the point is x,y coordinates given by the public key minus tag 0x04?

Comment: Yep, that's it precisely. You would still need to interpret the x, y coordinates as a set of fixed size big endian integers for them to be usable in the actual calculations of course. Note that link certs would only include parameters if they need to be changed (this is allowed).